# Creating a list of dataframes based on filter criteria

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

I would have a data set with a column `ID`. I filter them the data frame into winter and summer. I would like to split the data further based on the ID. In my actual data set there are over 100 IDs, so I don't want to make 100 data frames. Instead I would like to make a list of data frames. I used the `group_split` function to do this, but the number of list comes out uneven between winter and summer. I know for certain that there are the same number of IDs that should be in winter and summer. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
library(lubridate)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2011"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)
```

```
df$month <- month(df$date)
summer <- df%>% arrange(ID, date) %>%
  filter(month %in% 07:09) %>%
  group_by(ID, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  group_split(ID)


winter <- df%>% 
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  filter(month %in% c(01,02,03)) $>% 
  group_by(ID, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  # group_split(ID)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected

Comment: Your code doesn't work as written (`df` != `DF`) and `AnimalID` and `DateAndTime` don't exist. So it's hard to debug your problem. Try to include a [reprex].

Comment: Have you checked whether what you "know for certain" is true?

Comment: My expect output would be a list of data frames for each season (winter and summer). With each one of those list being a single ID from the larger data frame. The code should work now, I forgot to change those when posting. My apologies. Yes, when I filter them without the `group_split` function the number of individuals in both the summer and winter data frame come out to be the same.

Comment: I defined it. It was used to create a month column to make it easier to filter by months. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `split` will do what you want: produce a list of frames.

```r
summer <- filter(df, month(date) %in% 7:9)
head(summer)
#         date        x        y ID
# 1 2011-07-01 74958.44 842429.7  3
# 2 2011-07-02 64223.78 897607.8  4
# 3 2011-07-03 78843.54 829362.2  5
# 4 2011-07-04 60703.31 822962.0  1
# 5 2011-07-05 71328.44 872268.8  2
# 6 2011-07-06 68827.96 880618.3  3
str(split(summer, summer$ID))
# List of 5
#  $ 1:'data.frame':    18 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ date: Date[1:18], format: "2011-07-04" "2011-07-09" ...
#   ..$ x   : num [1:18] 60703 64986 79477 67815 70387 ...
#   ..$ y   : num [1:18] 822962 858762 897413 817728 838251 ...
#   ..$ ID  : int [1:18] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ 2:'data.frame':    18 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ date: Date[1:18], format: "2011-07-05" "2011-07-10" ...
#   ..$ x   : num [1:18] 71328 65414 64275 74286 76995 ...
#   ..$ y   : num [1:18] 872269 862579 818690 825991 847360 ...
#   ..$ ID  : int [1:18] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#  $ 3:'data.frame':    19 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ date: Date[1:19], format: "2011-07-01" "2011-07-06" ...
#   ..$ x   : num [1:19] 74958 68828 69431 76959 68538 ...
#   ..$ y   : num [1:19] 842430 880618 852488 874800 839197 ...
#   ..$ ID  : int [1:19] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
#  $ 4:'data.frame':    19 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ date: Date[1:19], format: "2011-07-02" "2011-07-07" ...
#   ..$ x   : num [1:19] 64224 66977 75101 64189 73444 ...
#   ..$ y   : num [1:19] 897608 845062 809777 850364 822869 ...
#   ..$ ID  : int [1:19] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
#  $ 5:'data.frame':    18 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ date: Date[1:18], format: "2011-07-03" "2011-07-08" ...
#   ..$ x   : num [1:18] 78844 77418 79762 78613 77485 ...
#   ..$ y   : num [1:18] 829362 867594 860007 819956 815058 ...
#   ..$ ID  : int [1:18] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
```